# whats is standard way of making custom Adapter

Tags: android

[**complete code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=whats%20is%20standard%20way%20of%20making%20custom%20Adapter)

> its a complete code of the Custom Adapter Class with Model Class ... but please help me its statndard or not.....?

"

```
public class CustAdapDeasiese extends BaseAdapter
{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<GetSetDisease> dataList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustAdapDeasiese(Context context, ArrayList<GetSetDisease> dataList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
        if(context!=null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        /********** Inflate spinner_rows.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.res_spinner, viewGroup, false);
        final GetSetDisease data = dataList.get(position);
        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        TextView txt_title             = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_res_spn_title);
        if(data!=null) {
            txt_title.setText(data.getDiseasName().toString());
        }
        return row;
    }
}
"
```

Comment: What do you mean by being standard? Your question is unclear to me. Up to my understanding you have incorporated the standard the `BaseAdapter.`

Answer (score 0):

It is already called "custom adapter" means you can do anything, change the adapter the way you want to be suitable with demands of your app. So there is no 'standard' way to do this